# Mini DisplayPort to HDMI cable to VGA/DVI display?

Tags: macbook-pro, hdmi, displayport, vga-adapter

I'm connecting a MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015) to an Epson PowerLite 811p Projector.  I need a 30-foot cable between them, and would prefer to use the HDMI cable I already have.

Is it possible to convert the signal twice, first from Mini Displayport to HDMI, then from HDMI to VGA or DVI?

Comment: How long is 'long'? You'll struggle to push the signal 15m over DVI alone, even without adaptors, unless they are powered converters.

Comment: 30 feet, edited to clarify!

Comment: I think your best bet is a single cable; less chance of error/signal loss.